# Wordpress $post->post_content breaks text editor formatting on front-end

Tags: wordpress

I write a text in Wordpress text editor as in image, with line breaks and everything
[image]
Only in my code if I put it this way

```
$post->post_content
```

On my site page it does not break the line the way I put it in the text editor
[image]
And if I put it this way in the code it breaks the lines and respects the same formatting of line breaks that I put in the text editor

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post();
the_content()
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please ask the question in a clearer way

Comment: see if you got a little lighter...haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `the_content()`, WordPress runs the post's content through a series of filters (the filter name is also `the_content`). One of them is wpautop that replaces blank lines with `<p>...</p>` tags.

You can either do that part yourself, or run all the filters outside the loop by using

```
echo apply_filters("the_content", $post->post_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$post->post_content` returns raw data. While if the quicktag  is used in a post to designate the “cut-off” point for the post to be excerpted, the_content() tag will only show the excerpt up to the  quicktag point on non-single/non-permalink post pages. By design, the_content() tag includes a parameter for formatting the  content and look, which creates a link to “continue reading” the full post.

`apply_filters('the_content', $content);` is meant to be used to apply formatting to raw post content.

Too get the same effect:

```
<?php
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
  echo $content;
?>
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/